# Printing float up to six decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I have an issue in printing a float number.
I tried:

```
a = 2
c = 4
print (str(c/a).format(1.6))
```

Output:

```
2.0
```

Required Output:

```
2.000000
```

How can I print up to 6 decimal places?

Comment: In your case, `print('%.6f' % 2)`. or better yet `print(str.format('{0:.6f}', 2))`

Comment: Your question is a duplicate. Look at how `str.format` is used in the answers to the other question and read the documentation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be accomplished by:

```
print("{:.6f}".format(your value here));
```